# Custom XML response in sails.js blueprint for a model?

Tags: sails.js

I am new to sails.js and I have a simple blueprint model set up. Right now, my controller and model are pretty much empty except for attribute definitions on the model.

After the model is created via POST, **I would like the response to be a custom XML response** (some plain text I generate essentially), not the standard JSON response. I figured that I could overwrite the entire create method on the controller, essentially copy-and-pasting the code from the default and just overwriting the response, but that seems really heavy too me.

There must be a better way to do this?

Note that I am only attempting to do this for this specific model, not generally.

Thanks!

Comment: This depends on how your application is setup in general. Is it purely and API? Do you have any view files? What is requesting the information, another server or an browser based client? Where does this create controller currently reside (is it in blueprints? if so do you require pubsub/sockets?) Is it just for create or for all actions on the model?

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to simply add the header as DigitalDesignDj mentioned.

```
/**
* TestController
*/
module.exports = {
    create: function(res, req) {
        // get your data
        var xml = 'some xml string';

        res.setHeader( "Content-type", "text/xml" );
        res.send(xml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change headers for a specific response.

`response.setHeader( "Content-type", "text/xml" );`

When you already have some XML for the `response.send()`

Answer (score 1):

If your result was to do this for all actions on that single model you could simply overwrite the toJSON method to generate XML instead of JSON in the model itself. Then if your running blueprints, it will spit out XML instead of json when you hit those endpoints.

However your question is specific to the create action. In this instance, I would ask if your running alternate view files for non ajax requests. And if not, just drop an view files into the create action that views/foo/create.[ejs,jade,ect...] with your xml layout. The response will see the view file and override the json output with that file. This means you have to change no code just add that single file.

Their are a dozen ways to accomplish this, and your question would need more detail (as mentioned on the comments) for a specific answer to your use case.